# SharePoint 2010 - Adding a Visual Web Part to a page C#

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a simple Visual Web Part in Visual Studio 2010. How can I now add this web part programatically to a specific Sharepoint 2010 page? I already have code that generates a One Column Wiki Page with a list view web part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [SPLimitedWebPartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager.aspx) object

```
SPLimitedWebPartManager webPartManager = homePage.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
SPList announcementsList = currentWeb.Lists["Announcements"];
ListViewWebPart announcementsWebPart = new ListViewWebPart();
announcementsWebPart = new ListViewWebPart();
announcementsWebPart.Title = announcementsList.Title;
announcementsWebPart.ZoneID = "Left";
announcementsWebPart.ListName = announcementsList.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
announcementsWebPart.TitleUrl = announcementsList.DefaultViewUrl;
announcementsWebPart.ViewGuid = announcementsList.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
webPartManager.AddWebPart(announcementsWebPart, announcementsWebPart.ZoneID, 1);
webPartManager.SaveChanges(announcementsWebPart);
```

Try [this](http://www.keirgordon.com/post/Add-Web-Part-to-Page-Programmatically.aspx) or [this](http://www.dhirajranka.com/?p=78).
[Jan Tielens post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2005/06/22/414283.aspx), while old is still relevant.

Comment: Thanks but this just adds a ListViewWebPart. I need to add a Visual Web Part that has been deployed as a .wsp. I can add it manually through the browser when in edit mode 'Insert - Web Part - Custom - VisualWebPart'

Comment: Replace ListViewWebPart with the name of the class from your visual web part. Any webpart that inherits from System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart can use SPLimitedWebPartManager.AddWebPart.

Comment: The two linkes below the code show how to load from your webpart gallery.

Answer (score 1):

```
1 - create sharepoint empty project
2 - create site definition
3 - create a webpart
4 - in onet.xml insert your webpart
5 - create a page to handle the webpart in onet folder
6 - create feature Site scope
7 - Deploy
8 - in sharepoint -> Create new Site / You site definiton / and voulá magic
```

;)